# typescript shot form notation of used Enum in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, interface

Is there any way to shorten this piece of code?
Basically I do not want to write A.a, A.b, etc. Some how I just want to write A and type script will understand it needs to be one of the enum values.

Thanks

```
enum A {
  a: 'one',
  b: 'two',
  c: 'three'
}

interface check {
  type: A.a|A.b|A.c
}
```

Answer (score 3):

enums should be used in below way

```
enum A {
  a: 'one',
  b: 'two',
  c: 'three'
}

interface check {
 type: A
}
```

in this way, check.type can have values 'one', 'two', 'three'

Comment: I did once but I got some error so I thought it does not work like that. But it is working now and I have no clue what did I do wrong at first.